# Браузер не применяет CSS файл

Tags: html, css, django

Изучаю Django и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что указанный в HTML файл стилей CSS не применяется в браузере. В меню разработчика возвращается ошибка `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/blog.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`.При этом путь указан верно, пробовал указать путь напрямую без использования шаблонов - ситуация та же.

Код HTML:

```
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Django Girls blog</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
```

CSS:

```
page-header {
    background-color: #ff9400;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 40px;
}

.page-header h1, .page-header h1 a, .page-header h1 a:visited, .page-header h1 a:active {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 36pt;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.content {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}

.date {
    color: #828282;
}

.save {
    float: right;
}

.post-form textarea, .post-form input {
    width: 100%;
}

.top-menu, .top-menu:hover, .top-menu:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
    float: right;
    font-size: 26pt;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.post {
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.post h1 a, .post h1 a:visited {
    color: #000000;
}
```

Сам файл лежит в blog\static\css\blog.css
Подскажите куда смотреть, что я упускаю? Спасибо.

Comment: DEBUG=True в настройках не забыли включить?

Comment: Скорее всего как писали выше выключен DEBUG режим. А в рабочем режиме Django сам не отдает статические файлы для этого можно использовать nginx например.

Comment: DEBUG=True включен.

Answer (score 1):

После перезагрузки сервера, браузер увидел файл CSS, но стили также не применялись.
В общем-то проблема была не в Django, а в моей кривой копипасте и невнимательном чтении учебника. В CSS я пишу стили с применением сторонних шрифтов, например:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}
```

Но, я в header HTML-файла я не указал ссылку на этот шрифт.
Также я копировал CCS-код и в самом начале в указании класса пропустил точку:

```
page-header {
    background-color: #ff9400;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 40px;
}
```